# PowerShell can't use the matching enum type?

Tags: powershell, types, parameters, enums

Am I doing something stupid here?

I specify that a function takes a particular enum type as an argument:

```
PS> add-type -AssemblyName System.ServiceProcess
PS> function test([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]$x) { Write-host $x $x.gettype() }
```

The type is most definitely in scope since I can access instances of it (and I imported the assembly manually):

```
PS> [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped
Stopped
```

Then when I try to pass the function an instance of said enum, it errors out:

```
PS> test [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped
test : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'x'. Cannot convert value
"[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped" to type "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus".
Error: "Unable to match the identifier name [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped to a valid
enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: Stopped, StartPending, StopPending,
Running, ContinuePending, PausePending, Paused"
At line:1 char:6
+ test [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [test], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,test
```

It's quite happy coercing a string, though:

```
PS> test 'Stopped'
Stopped System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are running into a small gotcha regarding parsing modes.  You can put parens around the argument and it will work:

```
test ([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped)
```

Alternatively, conversions from string to enum happen naturally, so you could write:

```
test Stopped
```

Here are a couple good links that discuss parsing modes:

- [About Parsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx)
- [Effective PowerShell Item 10: Understanding PowerShell Parsing Modes](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an enum value as a string but you don't pass the typename as part of the argument e.g. this works just fine:

```
PS> test Stopped
Stopped System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus
```

That said, when I'm calling .NET methods I prefer to use the fully qualified enum value instead of a string.  That's because .NET methods tend to have multiple overloads and those that take strings can confuse PowerShell when to comes to picking the right overload.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, PowerShell thinks I am sending it a string, rather than an enum object. You get the same error message if you quote the fully qualified name:

```
PS> test '[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped'
test : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'x'. Cannot convert value
"[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped" to type "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus".
Error: "Unable to match the identifier name [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped to a valid
enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: Stopped, StartPending, StopPending,
Running, ContinuePending, PausePending, Paused"
At line:1 char:6
+ test '[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped'
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [test], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,test
```

Putting the enum in parentheses to force PowerShell to evaluate it first does the trick:

```
PS> test ([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped)
Stopped System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not specifying the `$x` parameter correctly. It needs to be wrapped in a `param()` expression.

```
function test
{
    param(
        [ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]
        $x
    ) 
    Write-host $x $x.gettype() 
}
```

Plus you can omit the `System.` portion of any type name.

Comment: Pretty sure that's really old advice back from the PS1 days or something... As seen in the other answers, the syntax in the question works as expected. It's the call that's having some parsing problems.